# python--recursive list comprehension to apply lstrip on a list

Tags: python, regex, list, recursion, list-comprehension

I have two lists as follows

```
f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']
```

so i want to apply lstrip of each strings in f over all the items of list d,,so that i can get

```
d = ['fav_genre','fav_event','fav_type','fav_movie']
```

And i want to do it using list comprehension.
But i know i can do it in other ways also, like using a re.sub, applying replace on each time on list items of d

```
 #example
 d = [re.sub(r'.*fav', 'fav', x) for x in d] #####gives what i want
 ## but if fav (which in this case a matching pattern) is not there in d then this solution won't work
 ## d = ['fav_genre','sum_any_event','count_some_type','per_all_movie']
 #re.sub can't be applied on this d(as before) as no matching char like 'fav' found
```

So list compression is what i choose to do..

so far i have tried ..

```
d_one = [x.lstrip('count_') for x in d]   ###only count_ is stripped
# o/p- d-one = ['fav_genre', 'sum_fav_event', 'fav_type', 'per_fav_movie']
# so i c_n apply lstrip of each string from f on items of d
## why not apply all items lstrip in one go ### so tried
d_new = [x.lstrip(y) for y in f for x in d]
###['fav_genre', 'fav_event', 'count_fav_type', 'per_fav_movie', 'fav_genre', 'sum_fav_event', 'fav_type', 'per_fav_movie', 'fav_genre', 'sum_fav_event', 'count_fav_type', 'fav_movie']
```

So it gave me results for each iteration of lstrip applied

Please suggest how can i apply all lstrip in one go in a list comprehension (recursively). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think you actually want to use `lstrip` here.  `lstrip` doesn't remove string prefixes, as you seem to want, but rather removes prefixes consisting of any characters from the argument.  So if you try to remove `'count_'` from `"notable"`, you will get `"able"`.  I don't think you want that.

Comment: Can you please explain why it has to be recursive? Is this some twisted assignment? The best you can hope for is a function with one line if it has to be recursive.

Comment: @timgeb-yes, by recursive here, i mean , when i get each iteration result of lstrip applied (result) ,,,so why not apply second lstrip on first lstrip result till   last item of f...So recursive call to list f to get item and apply lstrip of that item over list d each time.

Comment: @TomKarzes- can you please explain if i apply lstrip('count_') on 'count_notable_authors' .. why the not before able is also replaced.But in other case 'count_xyz_author'  it only removes 'count_' and keeps 'xyz-author'..Just started working on python so not having deep conceptual idea..please reply why so??

Comment: Because `lstrip` doesn't do what you think it does.  If you give it a prefix of `'count_'`, it's just a set of characters, no different from `'ntc_uo'`.  It is *unordered*.  It will keep removing any of those characters from the front of the string until it encounters a character that is not in the set.

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution for you that I believe handles all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
>>> d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']
>>> [s[len(([p for p in f if s.startswith(p)]+[""])[0]):] for s in d]
['fav_genre', 'fav_event', 'fav_type', 'fav_movie']
```

I believe this handles all of the cases as intended.

Comment: -Thanks a lot!!! You made my day(as i argued with someone that this can be done via List Comprehension and you should be  totally creditable for making me able to keep my words )...

Answer (score 3):

The following approach could be used, which creates a suitable regular expression based on `f`:

```
import re

f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']

re_prefix = re.compile(r'^({})'.format('|'.join(f)))
print [re_prefix.sub('', entry) for entry in d]
```

Or as a one-liner (not as efficient):

```
print [re.sub(r'^({})'.format('|'.join(f)), '', entry) for entry in d]
```

Giving you the following output:

```
['fav_genre', 'fav_event', 'fav_type', 'fav_movie']
```

Comment: @Martian Evans-really a better one across,But i have to accept Tom's Answer as i don't want to insult my Question's header...

Answer (score 1):

This what you're looking for?

```
>>> f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
>>> d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']
>>> [x[len(y):] for x in d for y in f if x.startswith(y)]
['fav_event', 'fav_type', 'fav_movie']
```

EDIT:
The more I poke at this, the more I'm finding it not possible with list comprehension. The problem seems to be including the non-matching condition, but a simple 'else' causes each item in d to be included when iterating on the other items in f.

For instances

```
>>> [x[len(y):] if x.startswith(y) else x for x in d for y in f
['fav_genre', 'fav_genre', 'fav_genre', 'fav_event', 'sum_fav_event', 'sum_fav_event', 'count_fav_type', 'fav_type', 'count_fav_type', 'per_fav_movie', 'per_fav_movie', 'fav_movie']
```

This creates a new list with too many items.

Adding another condition to the list comp generates a syntax error:

```
[x[len(y):] if x.startswith(y) else x if x[len(y):] not in f for x in d for y in f]
File "<stdin>", line 1
  [x[len(y):] if x.startswith(y) else x if x[len(y):] not in f for x in d for y in f]
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even if we could get this with list comprehension, a function would be much more readable:

```
def strip_prefixes(prefixes, mylist):
    for element in mylist:
        for x in prefixes:
            if element.startswith(x):
                element = element[len(x):]
    return mylist
```

Comment: @Willnx-You are also missing fav_genre in output...which is not startswith(item from f)...

Comment: Good point Satya, I hadn't noticed that when I first saw this solution but you're correct of course.

Comment: You could store the result of the list comprehension in a set but as you understand, the list comprehension is not suited for this job. At least not suited for "modifying" the output of the listed entries. For that, you should use a well suited function to transform the output. the for part of the comprehension is used to combined and the if part to reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother doing that with a list comprehension much. A list comprehension if pretty much like a map/reduce syntax sugar. You'll get a much easier to read solution by using simple functions.

```
import re

f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']
def makeTrimmer(patterns):
    regex = re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(patterns))

    def trimmer(string):

        old_string = string             
        new_string = re.sub(regex, "", old_string)

        while len(old_string) != len(new_string):
            old_string = new_string
            new_string = re.sub(regex, "", old_string)

        return new_string

    return trimmer

trimmer = makeTrimmer(f)
vals = [trimmer(x) for x in d]
print vals
```

As you can see, the `trimmer` function is quite readable, you could probably do that within the list comprehension but there is no easy way to do that. Because the if part of the list comprehension is working pretty much like a filter on the list on things to output. The for part is combining entries and the first part is building the entry output. In your case, you only have to build the correct output based on the multiple prefixes... In other words you're not trying to combine all prefixes with all values into multiple outputs and you're not filtering any result.

My method could be probably achieved with lambdas but that would be ugly most probably.

Non recursive method without lambdas:

```
vals = [
    re.sub(re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(f)), "", x)
    for x in d
]                      
print vals
```

And here's the full recursive one using anonymous lambdas:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

f = ['sum_','count_','per_']
d = ['fav_genre','sum_fav_event','count_fav_type','per_fav_movie']

vals = [
    (lambda a, *b: a(a, *b))(
        (lambda loop, newstring, oldstring:
            newstring
            if len(newstring) == len(oldstring) else
                loop(
                    loop,
                    newstring,
                    re.sub(re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(f)), "", x)
                )
        ),
        re.sub(re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(f)), "", x),
        x
    )
    for x in d
]

print vals
```

This is pretty much the same thing as the above method except that we're using a recursive method to call for further filtering, so this method clears out things like `sum_count_per_fun_avg` to `fun_avg`.

Also, don't use the lambda method, it's inefficient.

But here's a more efficient lambda version:

```
vals = [
    (lambda regex:
        (lambda a, *b: a(a, *b))(
            (lambda loop, newstring, oldstring:
                newstring
                if len(newstring) == len(oldstring) else
                    loop(                                                                                                                   
                        loop,
                        newstring,
                        re.sub(regex, "", x)
                    )
            ),
            re.sub(regex, "", x),
            x
        )
    )(re.compile("^(%s)" % "|".join(f)))
    for x in d
]
```

We compile the regex only once. But recursion in python is still a problem so you shouldn't use recursion much.

Answer (score 1):

I am about to go to sleep but was working on this.  I think it's probably not the best idea to do it this way as it is a lot of loops and is not that readable.  It's also not quite right.

```
d_new = set([(x,y) for x in [x.split(y)[1] for y in f for x in d if x.startswith(y)] for y in [x for x in d if x.startswith('fav')]])
```

It currently puts them into tuples, you could add another x for x in within the set to extract the distinct tuple pairs.  At this point though I don't even think it's useful or worth it to use list comprehension, but if you really want to use one this might give you a start.

**Edit:**

Code comes out looking like this:

> [('fav_movie', 'fav_genre'), ('fav_event', 'fav_genre'), ('fav_type',
>   'fav_genre')]